# The properties of commutator subgroups in finite groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $P \in Syl_p(G)$ such that $(\vert F \vert , \vert P \vert)=1$ and $[F,P,P]=1$. Then why $[P,F]=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the theory of finite groups and co-prime actions and commutators. In general, if $A$ acts via automorphisms on $G$, with $(|G|,|A|)=1$, then $[G,A,A]=[G,A]$. For a proof see Lemma 4.29 in [I.M. Isaacs, Finite Group Theory.](http://mathhome.ir/my_doc/mathhome/Ketabkhane/Books/English%20Resources/l7/New%20Folder%20%283%29/__Finite_Group_Theory__Graduate_Studies_in_Mathematics__copy%28isaacs%29.pdf) In your case, $P$ acts via conjugation on $F$ since the latter is normal.

Comment: No thanks, and if you deem my answer to be correct, please tick it as such.

Comment: Im so sorry, i made a mistake and i clicked the wrong! I fixed it now your answer is correct. I apologize again Dear Nicky Hekster

Comment: No problem, thanks for acknowledging!